Can we automate API calls used in my iOS App and validate its response
Is it a good idea to automate API calls used in my mobile APP in XCtests and check if response is in expected format. I want to test all the API calls used inside my app at one place rather than testing each feature which internally calls that API. This way I want to sure that my API's are working. Is there any renowned way to do it.

"and check if response is in expected format" This is testing the server because you say you want to check the server response. But you also say you want to test the API calls used inside the app. Which is it, you want to test your app's response or the server's payload's is in expected payload?

I want to test server's payload's is in expected format

Do not test the Internet or the API server. Your tests should work perfectly with the network completely cut off.
You can (and should) mock the Internet for purposes of testing, and test whether your code calls the API as expected and whether, when the mock response comes back, it deals correctly with that response. The standard approach is to subclass URLProtocol (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlprotocol).

Actually I want to test the live API response, as the API response I am receiving from web is not reliable and I don't want to break my App because of it.

I stand by my answer. You need to work out your differences with the server people, or build robustness in the face of unpredictability into your app. But you should not involve the actual server in your app's unit tests. That is what you asked and that is my answer.
